# Sending Image in iMessageExtension

Tags: ios, swift3, imessage, imessage-extension

I wonder whether it is possible to send an image via message in iMessageExtension. I am developing an app where sender and receiver need to see the same image.
Basically here is DetailViewController with ImageView and ImageView.image should image sent via message.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this. If you are just trying to send a regular  non-animated image you can avoid having to save temporary files to disk (which you would send by calling `insertAttachment` on your `conversation`) and instead use `MSMessageTemplateLayout` directly. You can do something like this:

```
let message = MSMessage()
let layout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()
layout.image = myImage
message.layout = layout
conversation.insert(message, completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: I mean that when receiver presses the message it will open another viewcontroller and in that view controller will show image of image sent via message

Comment: Basically here is DetailViewController with ImageView and ImageView.image should image sent via message

Answer (score 1):

The below code captures a view and essentially screenshots it, then shares it via iMessage. Tested this on iPhone 7 running iOS 10, works.

```
    let name = ""
    let desc = ""

    if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {
        let messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self
        if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendAttachments() {
            let img = viewToCapture.getSnapshotImage()
            let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)
            messageVC.addAttachmentData(imageData!, typeIdentifier: "image/png", filename: "image.png")
        } else {
            print("Message can't send attachments")
        }
        self.present(messageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    let messageComposeViewController = configuredMessageViewController(name, detail: desc)

    if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {
        self.present(messageComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        shareStuff.msgError()
    }
```

Note that the above uses this UIView extension to capture the image from the screen. If this is your first extension, it's global so just put the code where ever you want (but not within a class):

```
public func getSnapshotImage() -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, self.isOpaque, 0)
    self.drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
    let snapshotImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return snapshotImage
}
```

Comment: Nice sample but may confuse people - it is composing within a normal app, not an iMessage Extension.